# Finding and Keeping Unique Values WITHIN a row

Tags: sql, oracle

Hoping you can help with this.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: Starting Table]

I want to add columns that retain the first 2 unique values (if applicable) of a given variable to look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most people here want data as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: @jarlh did that edit work? thanks for the advice

Comment: Better. But with formatted text people can copy and paste, which makes it easier to test and reproduce. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 2):

This assumes you don't want any special treatment for nulls.

```
select indiv_id, trip_band, 
        group_shot_code_1 as final_group1,
         case
      when  group_shot_code_2 != group_shot_code_1 then group_shot_code_2
      when  group_shot_code_3 != group_shot_code_1 then group_shot_code_3
       when  group_shot_code_4 != group_shot_code_1 then group_shot_code_4
       when  group_shot_code_5 != group_shot_code_1 then group_shot_code_5
    end as final_group2
From your_table;
```

---

Also I haven't been able to test it, but it looks okay. Let me know if there are any syntax errors you can't fix.